# Extending a typescript file's "include" without overriding original settings file

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript file:

```
tsconfig.lib.json:

{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.stories.ts"
  ]
}
```

I'd like to also include the files inside my original tsconfig.json. How can I include more files without overriding the original "include" settings?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't, _files, include and exclude from the inheriting config file overwrite those from the base config file_ https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#configuration-inheritance-with-extends

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not supported (at least currently)

> **files**, **include** and **exclude** from the inheriting config file overwrite those from the base config file

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends)